# Missing Polymer Element

Tags: dart, polymer-1.0, angular-dart

I've installed polymer based on the Dart, Angular 2, and Polymer Together demo. I've got a couple of elements to work so far. I now want to use iron-scroll-target-behavior. I wasn't able to import it into my dart program because it's not in my packages. Is there something special I have to do with this element that I didn't for the others?

I tried the install link from the catalog:

```
bower install iron-scroll-target-behavior
```

I get the error:

```
EINVALID Name must be lowercase, can contain digits, dots, dashes, "@" or spaces
```

This is my pubspec that I set up base on the demo:

```
name: jazzcat
description: A catalog of jazz music
version: 0.0.1
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.13.0 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  angular2: 2.0.0-beta.17
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  polymer: ^1.0.0-rc.17
  polymer_elements: ^1.0.0-rc.8
  web_components: ^0.12.0
  http:
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/index.html
- angular2:
    resolved_identifiers:
        Window: 'dart:html'
    platform_directives:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_DIRECTIVES'
    platform_pipes:
    - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
- $dart2js:
    $include: '**/*.bootstrap.initialize.dart'
    minify: true
    commandLineOptions:
    - --trust-type-annotations
    - --trust-primitives
```

Comment: It might be too new. There is currently work in progress to get the elements updated.

Comment: I checked the homepage on github. It looks to be five months old. How can I get it when it's available? Do I just keep upgrading my dependencies until it shows?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer_elements/pulls

Comment: Tests need to be ported manually, that's the main part of the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While waiting for the real thing to come along, I created a substitute. The element I wish to scroll is the paper-listbox. I just added a css class to the template:

```
.scroll-list  {
  height: 40em;       /* arbitrary height. Should be based on window height */
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Then on the listbox itself:

```
<paper-listbox class="scroll-list">
```